# How to specify SCT(Signed Certificate Timestamp) data to send as a TLS extension in openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I want to send SCT(Signed Certificate Timestamp) data on server side as a TLS extension, But I did not find any functions that support this operation in the openssl manpage(https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/).Thanks for help if there is any suggesstions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for sending this. However, you can use the `SSL_CTX_use_serverinfo_ex` or `SSL_CTX_use_serverinfo` functions to send arbitrary extensions data which should be sufficient for your purpose.

See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CTX_use_serverinfo_ex.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will look into this manpage